# Is it possible for a wearable app to detect if the user has disabled interruptions?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a wearable app which displays some additional GUI whenever the the wearable is displaying an incoming phone call.

However if the user has configured the watch to show no interruptions then it does not display anything when there is an incoming phone call.
Is there an API to determine how the user has configured the watch interruption settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this information is exposed in `NotificationListener`. Specifically:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onInterruptionFilterChanged(int)

Comment: Thanks. Will the user need to explicitly grant notification access to my app via the settings to use this? Also I don't need to monitor for changes to the filter, therefore is it possible to simply call getCurrentInterruptionFilter() somehow without having to have a permanently running service?

Comment: Yes, user needs to grant explicitly permission. This is one of the most sensitive permission (you can read somebody's private data).